# "Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:12:9-14:91 to override."

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I'm trying to compile an Android application that uses react-native and I get:

> /Users/dorianmariefr/src/socializus/react-native/android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:14:13-88 Error:
> Attribute meta-data#org.unimodules.core.AppLoader#react-native-headless@value value=(org.unimodules.adapters.react.apploader.RNHeadlessAppLoader) from [:unimodules-react-native-adapter] AndroidManifest.xml:14:13-88
> is also present at [:expo-modules-core] AndroidManifest.xml:14:13-86 value=(expo.modules.adapters.react.apploader.RNHeadlessAppLoader).
> Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:12:9-14:91 to override.

Seems like I need to merge two values from two librairies:

```
meta-data#org.unimodules.core.AppLoader#react-native-headless@value
```

From `:unimodules-react-native-adapter` and `:expo-modules-core`.

I'm not sure if I should put `org.unimodules.adapters.react.apploader.RNHeadlessAppLoader` or `expo.modules.adapters.react.apploader.RNHeadlessAppLoader` and how I should set those values.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: Actually I needed to remove the unimodules package and move to the expo package, see https://docs.expo.dev/bare/installing-expo-modules

This fixed it for me:

```xml
<manifest
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  package="com.social.firebase.example.socializus"
>
...
  <application
    android:name=".MainApplication"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
  >
...
    <meta-data
      tools:replace="android:value"
      android:name="org.unimodules.core.AppLoader#react-native-headless"
      android:value="org.unimodules.adapters.react.apploader.RNHeadlessAppLoader"
    />
```

(now getting a new error though)